# Rust Wasm. Как получить доступ и добавить элемент web_sys::HtmlFrameElement

Tags: rust, wasm

Создаю глобальный объект window.
В head созданного объекта, кладу iframe, при этом, браузер сам подкладывает document с HTML.
Пытаюсь получить доступ к head документа внутри iframe, создавая еще один контекст window.
Далее, кладу в head созданного в iframe документа еще один iframe, но это пока не важно (падает раньше).
Этот код компилируется, но в браузере не создается глобальный объект global_window_too.
Падает dyn_ref ::<web_sys::HtmlFrameElement >(), указывая в консоли, что called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value' на этой строке кода.

Как сделать динамическое приведение dyn_ref ::<web_sys::HtmlFrameElement >() к content_window() в ноде айфрейма, или получить доступ другим способом?

```
 let global_window = web_sys::window().unwrap(); 
 let document = global_window.document().unwrap(); 
 let head = document.head().unwrap(); 

 let iframe = document.create_element( "iframe")?;
 let iframe_append_head =  head
                          .append_child(&iframe)
                          .unwrap();
 let global_window_too = iframe_append_head
                        .dyn_ref::<web_sys::HtmlFrameElement >()
                        .unwrap()
                        .content_window()
                        .unwrap();
```

Comment: Это начинает работать в Хроме, если dyn_ref() заменить на unchecked_into(). В Файерфорсе не работает ни с проверкой, ни без.

Comment: А точно должен быть `web_sys::HtmlFrameElement`, а не `web_sys::HtmlIFrameElement`?

Comment: Вроде бы Frame, потому как IFrame в web_sys не находит